# FormData is empty in NextJS 14v

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, frontend, multipartform-data

```
const Page = () => {


    const [categories, setCategories] = useState([]);
    const [productName, setProductName] = useState();
    const [categoryID, setCategoryID] = useState();
    const [productDescription, setProductDescription] = useState();
    const [price, setPrice] = useState();
    const [rating, setRating] = useState();
    const [image, setProductImg] = useState();

    const router = useRouter();
    const form = new FormData()

    useEffect(() => {
        GetCategories(setCategories)
    }, []);
    const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        /* const formData = {
            productName,
            categoryID,
            productDescription,
            price,
            rating,
            image
        } */


        form.set('productName', productName)
        form.set('categoryID', categoryID)
        form.set('productDescription', productDescription)
        form.set('price', price)
        form.set('rating', rating)
        form.set('image', image)

        console.log(form)

        const jwt = await GenerateJWT(productName);
        await axios.post('/api/v1/products', form, {
            headers: {
                JWT: jwt,
                "Content-Type": 'multipart/form-data'
            }
        })
            .then(data => {
                console.log(data)
                alert('Product created successful');
                router.push('/');
            })
            .catch(err => {
                console.error(`Error to create a new product -> ${JSON.stringify(err)}`)
                console.log(err)
                alert('Error to create a new product, please try again later.')
            });
    };

    return (
        <div>
            <form
                onSubmit={(e) => {
                    handleSubmit(e);
                }}
            >
                <label htmlFor="productName">Product Name</label>
                <input type="text"
                    name="productName"
                    onChange={(e) => setProductName(e.target.value)}
                />
                <label htmlFor="categories">Categories</label>
                <select name="categories" id="categories"

                    onChange={(e) => setCategoryID(e.target.value)}
                >
                    {
                        categories.length && categories != undefined ?
                            categories.map(category => (
                                <option key={category.id} value={category.id}>{category.category}</option>
                            ))

                            : <option>Loading categories</option>
                    }
                </select>


                <label htmlFor="productDescription">Product description</label>
                <input type="text"
                    name="productDescription"
                    onChange={(e) => setProductDescription(e.target.value)}
                />
                <label htmlFor="price">Price</label>
                <input type="number"
                    name="price"
                    onChange={(e) => setPrice(e.target.value)}
                />
                <label htmlFor="rating">Rating</label>
                <input type="number"
                    name="rating"
                    onChange={(e) => setRating(e.target.value)}
                />
                <label htmlFor="productImg">Product image</label>
                <input type="file"
                    name="productImg"
                    onChange={(e) => setProductImg(e.target.files[0])}
                />
                <button type="submit">Create product</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    );
}

export default Page;
```

I am developing a form that communicates with the backend of my app with NextJS in its version number 14 and I try to send data through the FormData(), but the data is not saved in it, running the console.log(form) leaves the FormData empty. I thought it would be because of the React states but it still doesn't work and I'm already going crazy lol.

Thank you very much in advance and I hope I can resolve this later.

Answer (score 1):

Move the `new FormData()` initialization to the function:

```js
const handleSubmit = async (e) => {

  const form = new FormData()

  form.set('productName', productName)
  form.set('categoryID', categoryID)
  form.set('productDescription', productDescription)
  form.set('price', price)
  form.set('rating', rating)
  form.set('image', image)

  console.log(form)
}
```

And instead of adding each form field to the FormData object you can give the FormData constructor the form element as an argument:

```js
const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
  const form = new FormData(e.target)

  console.log(form)
}
```

Comment: I tried it before and it didn't work either :(

Comment: When you console form in client side it shows empty but whenever you console in server side it shows the values. use with @Ahmed suggestion